# How to prevent duplicates of SelectItem in Set collection

Tags: jsf, duplicates, selectonemenu

I am trying to add  SelectItem objects to Set collection. However, duplicate values are being added. Is there any way to prevent these duplicate values?

```
for(String s: list) {       
  Set<SelectItem> typeSet = new HashSet<SelectItem>();
  typeSet.add(new SelectItem(s));
}
```

Comment: That's basic Java. Just take care about `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods in the objects to prevent duplicates in the `Set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Set<String>` instead of `Set<SelectItem>`. The `SelectItem#equals()`/`#hashCode()` isn't implemented at all to take the actual value into account.

```
private Set<String> typeSet;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    List<String> list = getItSomehow();
    typeSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>(list);
}
```

It's since JSF2 just usable on `<f:selectItems>` as well.

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.typeSet}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Comment: BalusC, similar to your suggested code, I used SortedSet interface: `SortedSet<String> typeSet = new TreeSet<String>();` which does the sorting of String values and added all these values to List<SelectItem>

Comment: You do not per se need `List<SelectItem>`. You can also just feed the `Set<String>` directly to it, as answered.